# Redis default configuration and utilization

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, performance, redis, cm-redissession

We did install Redis server 3.0.7 which has made our Magento store 1.9.x a bit better than before, but I just need to ask that all settings which comes out of the box in Redis is fine? or do I need to tune into something as we have much RAM available on machine and I want to cache as much as possible I can.

Also, when I check Redis utilization by running

```
redis-cli info | grep used_memory_human
```

it just returns some MB's like 3.72M or less than that(while when using file system caching in Magento it grows to much more) why is that?, can I somewhere define that as much memory Redis can use out of as much Gigs of RAM or is it kind of autoscale which goes up and down according to need?

Comment: you can set max ram redis can use, otherwise it will go infinite, but all objects have ttl, and will be deleted -> http://redis.io/topics/config    scroll down

Comment: @MagenX Ok, so it is smart enough with default settings to upscale as it needs to be. But, why `redis-cli info | grep used_memory_human` returns with some Mbytes like 3.7M while when saving on disk it uses much space than this. Could it be something like it flushes every second after query finishes?